# Extracting rows from start date and end dates that contain specific value in R

Tags: r, time

I have a data frame which has a column of ID numbers and dates each time ID logged into website. i need to calculate the total number of times the 'ID' logged into the site between specified interval.

I want to create a function that will input `login_check(startdate, enddate, ID)`
in argument create a new dataframe column of ID number and each row reflects her each login attempt within time interval

Then i can use the `length()` function to calculate total number of logins within time frame

Can someone please help me with creating the dataframe for specific ID within time frame?

Data:

```
structure(list(Order_ID = c(69L, 3025L, 3549L, 27L, 4561L, 2429L ), Date = structure(c(17899, 17921, 17925, 17923, 17917, 17919 ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share reproducibe example using dput().

Comment: structure(list(Order_ID = c(69L, 3025L, 3549L, 27L, 4561L, 2429L
), Date = structure(c(17899, 17921, 17925, 17923, 17917, 17919
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: there are multiple same order ID's in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::filter` can be used to filter a dataset based on your conditions.

```
logins <- structure(list(Order_ID = c(69L, 3025L, 3549L, 27L, 4561L, 2429L ), Date = structure(c(17899, 17921, 17925, 17923, 17917, 17919 ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") 

login_check <- function(startdate, enddate, ID) {
  dplyr::filter(logins, Order_ID == ID, Date >= startdate, Date <= enddate)
}

login_check('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', 3025)
#> Order_ID       Date
#> 1     3025 2019-01-25
```

Or, if you prefer base R

```
login_check <- function(startdate, enddate, ID) {
  logins[logins$Order_ID == ID & logins$Date >= startdate & logins$Date <= enddate,]
}
```

Or using `subset`

```
login_check <- function(startdate, enddate, ID) {
  subset(logins, Order_ID == ID & Date >= startdate & Date <= enddate)
}
```